# Viewing map tiles from Maperitive in leaflet or openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, maperitive

I generated tiles in Maperative. Created following html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
         <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px" id="map"></div>
          <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
          <script>
        map = new L.Map('map');

    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    var osmUrl='Maperitive\Tiles\{z}\{x}\{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 16, attribution: osmAttrib});      

    // start the map in South-East England
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(59.55, 30.09),13);
    map.addLayer(osm);
        var popup = L.popup();

        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(map);
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

, but do not see a map - only a form for map with +- buttons. What could be a problem?

I configured both the openlayers and leaflet, but it seems that this programs seek wrong folder/folder/file.png names on coordinates I provide. But I have no idea how to set this names in Maperative, I see many people generate tiles using mapnik, but as I understand, to do this I need to set up a database and something else. Maybe there is an easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better specify the full path to the tiles. In Openlayers I added these lines:

```
    var MyMapnikLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("myMapnik", "file:///D:/Tiles/myMapnik/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 16, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true, visibility: false});
    map.addLayer(MyMapnikLayer);
```

This is for Windows; Linux and Mac might have different ways to give absolute paths.

You can also take a look at the error console of your browser to see if something else is wrong.

Comment: No errors, after adding absolute path nothing changes, the same result. Can you provide me with your html file?

Comment: No need html, updated question.

Comment: Op, found mistakes. I mixed up longitude and latitude. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to resolve your script, but here's a simple page on my end that's shorter, doesn't need leaflet-src.js, and is working just fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet.css" />
</head>
  <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="lib/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [18.512224413095872, 73.868436919390348],
    zoom: 12,
    minZoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 15,
    maxBounds: [
    [18.443790655688225, 73.741131698096311],
    [18.672919555595893, 73.955365096533811]
    ]
});
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Map tiles generated for local use by <a href="http://maperitive.net">Maperitive</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.' }).addTo(map);

/* //Uncomment this section if you want to get the longitude, latitude co-ordinates in a popup on clicking a point on the screen.
var popup = L.popup();
        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("" + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(map);
        }

map.on('click', onMapClick);
*/

</script>
</body>
</html>
```