# Viewing map tiles generated from Maperitive in leaflet or openlayers

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, maperitive, tile-server

for few days i have been working on developing my own osm tile server.
I tried it on linux as well as on windows,
no complete success till now.

I Have to make tile server on both windows and linux.

for windows i used Maperitive and succeeded in generating tiles and then i used 
this guys code

```
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84697/viewing-map-tiles-from-maperitive-in-leaflet-or-openlayers
```

now the prob is tiles are not showing up

Do i need to instal some Apache module for it ?
My tiles are kept here

```
C:\Profiles\Maperitive\Tiles
```

Where as i am opening html file from server

```
http://localhost:8080/mwork/maperitive_test1/index_leaf.html
```

which is kept in here

```
C:\Profiles\ApachePHP\apache\www\mwork\maperitive_test1
```

```
</head>
<body>
     <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px" id="map"></div>
      <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet-src.js"></script>
      <script>
    map = new L.Map('map');

// create the tile layer with correct attribution
var osmUrl='C:\Profiles\Maperitive\TilesMaperitive\Tiles\{z}\{x}\{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors';
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 16, attribution: osmAttrib});      

// start the map in South-East England
map.setView(new L.LatLng(73.054519,33.707173 ),13);
map.addLayer(osm);
    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(map);
    }

    map.on('click', onMapClick);

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need a special apache module. You don't even need a webserver at all because you can just to open `file:///C:/Profiles/ApachePHP/apache/www/mwork/maperitive_test1/index_leaf.html` in your browser.

The problem is your `osmUrl`. Either you have to make `C:\Profiles\Maperitive\Tiles` available through your webserver. Or you have to replace the URL with `file:///C:/Profiles/Maperitive/Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

Additionally there is a typo in your URL, `Maperitive\TilesMaperitive\Tiles` should probably just be `Maperitive\Tiles` instead.